# "ReactJs" reset the State but not the unique id

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple form and I need to reset the state after each submit but keep the old id and build on it (get the next id based on the previous one)

```
this.state = {
  id: this.nextUniqueId();
  name: "Jhon",
}   

hSubmit = () => {    
  this.setState({    
    id: ????
    name: "",    
  });
};    

render(){
  return(
    <div> 
      <form onSubmit={this.hSubmit}> 
        <input type= "submit" /> 
        <br/> 
      </form>
    </div>
  );   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functional setState https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    id: prevState.id + 1, // or whatever
    name: "",
}));
```

Comment: Didn't notice you could run that function inside of setState... cool!

Comment: @SethMcClaine Yes functional setState is pretty interesting as has some advantages, you can check this link for more info: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Answer (score 1):

Just get the previous state id and add to it during your set state

```
hSubmit = () => {    
  this.setState({    
    id: this.state.id++,
    name: "",    
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I guess somehow this doesnot work id : null but thanks for your try

Comment: I see @Anas solution worked for you, but if you were interested in this solution you could `console.log(this.state.id)` and confirm you have access to it (which you should if you can use `this.setState`). If you don't you likely need to bind `this` to `hSubmit`